# Why doesn't Android's file /data/system/packages.xml have permission on read for others?

Tags: android, package, native

In Android there is a file with information about packages: "/data/system/packages.xml".

-rw-rw---- system   system     353111 2013-01-01 02:00 packages.xml

It seems this file doesn't contain any secret information. Nevertheless there are no permissions on read/write operations for other users.

From master:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/java/com/android/server/pm/Settings.java

```
Settings(Context context, File dataDir) {
  mContext = context;
  mSystemDir = new File(dataDir, "system");
  mSystemDir.mkdirs();
  FileUtils.setPermissions(mSystemDir.toString(),
  FileUtils.S_IRWXU|FileUtils.S_IRWXG
        |FileUtils.S_IROTH|FileUtils.S_IXOTH,
        -1, -1);
  mSettingsFilename = new File(mSystemDir, "packages.xml");
  mBackupSettingsFilename = new File(mSystemDir, "packages-backup.xml");
  mPackageListFilename = new File(mSystemDir, "packages.list");
  FileUtils.setPermissions(mPackageListFilename, 0660, SYSTEM_UID, PACKAGE_INFO_GID);
  // Deprecated: Needed for migration
  mStoppedPackagesFilename = new File(mSystemDir, "packages-stopped.xml");
  mBackupStoppedPackagesFilename = new File(mSystemDir, "packages-stopped-backup.xml");
 }
```

At the same time I implemented a simple Android activity. It just gets an information about all the installed packages.

```
package com.example.com.example.myfirst_epic_app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

//my
import android.content.pm.*;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;

import java.util.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void buttonClick(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        try {
            List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            textView.setText("Found pack");
            Log.i("Hello!!!", "Message after pack was found");

            for (PackageInfo cur_pack : packs) {
                Log.i("Hello!!!", "Name="+(cur_pack.packageName));
                for (Signature sig : cur_pack.signatures) {
                    Log.i(""+cur_pack.packageName, "Signature : " + sig.toCharsString());
                }
            }

        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            textView.setText("Not found");
        }

    }

}
```

This simple application has any privileges and is signed by debug key.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.com.example.myfirst_epic_app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.com.example.myfirst_epic_app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I downloaded "/data/system/packages.xml" file from device (I have a rooted Android image). 
As a result my application read and printed in LOG information about all the packages were installed on my device without any problems.

Questions:

1) It is clear that nobody must write to the file packages.xml. But if everyone can read information from "packages.xml" through Android API why didn't Android developers add permission on read for other users? for example:

-rw-rw-r-- system   system     353111 2013-01-01 02:00 packages.xml

2) Also I would like to know how to read information from packages.xml in native program without interaction with Android API?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.